HTTP Error 500 after cPanel restore [Moodle]
So I accidentally deleted my moodle directory in cPanel.
I have done home directory and database restore with jetbackup5.
But after it was done, I can't access the url which said HTTP ERROR 500. Anyone got same problem before?

There is a data folder too, was that backed up/restored? The folder location will be the value for $CFG->dataroot  = '/home/example/moodledata'; in 'config.php in the Moodle root directory

Sorry for the late reply, It was already fixed based on the error log provided. Turn out the restoration I did was not complete at the time. Thanks for the reply

It was already fixed based on the error log provided. Turn out the restoration I did was not complete at the time
